# How to use multiple where conditions in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

This Query is working

```
    $conditions = [
        'status' => '1',
        'country' => "DK"
    ];
        $offers = Offers::where($conditions)->get();
```

How can i use LIKE %% in this

When i tried this in single condition , its working

```
      $offers = Offers::where('country' , 'LIKE' , '%DK%')->get();
```

Comment: Add more `where` calls? `where('country', 'LIKE', '%DK%')->where('something', 'LIKE', '%condition%')` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$conditions = [
    'status' => '1',
    'country' => "DK"
];
$offers = Offers::where('country' , 'LIKE' , '%DK%')->where($conditions)->get();
```

You can chain your where clauses as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use where multiple times so you can try something like:

```
$offers = Offers::where('country' , 'LIKE' , '%DK%')
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->get();
```

I didn't test this but you can try also like this: ( It might work but I'm note sure )

```
$conditions = [
    'status' => '1',
    'country' => "LIKE %DK%"
];
$offers = Offers::where($conditions)->get();
```

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I think including `LIKE` in the condition array may cause problems with SQL Injection escaping.

Comment: Maybe the best way to do is with multiple wheres